# Apache camel Spring-Boot kafka component auto-configuration

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I'm trying to set application level apache camel kafka component properties using spring-boot auto-configuration.
I have included dependancy as per apache camel documentation (camel version 3.11.*)- https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/kafka-component.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-kafka-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Application.yml contains kafka compoenet properties as below

```
camel:
    component:
        kafka:
            brokers: localhost:9092
            header-deserializer: <package>.ByteToStringHeaderDeserializer
            header-serializer: <package>.ByteToStringHeaderSerializer
```

ByteToStringHeaderDeserializer implements KafkaHeaderDeserializer interface &
ByteToStringHeaderSerializer implements KafkaHeaderSerializer interface.

Camel route for consumer

```
from("kafka:test")
    .log("Message received from Kafka : ${body}")
    .log("Message Header : ${in.headers.NAME}")
```

Out of these properties 'brokers' seems to be working, but headers are not getting serialized / deserialized. If I create bean for the same classes and use it on the route it's working.

```
from("kafka:test?kafkaHeaderDeserializer=#kafkaHeaderDeserializerCustom")
    .log("Message received from Kafka : ${body}")
    .log("Message Header : ${in.headers.NAME}")
```

Can someone please help what could be the issue.